# 仮想通貨の価格を固定するようなtradingbotのアルゴリズムのようなものをありますでしょうか？

Tags: python

任意の１つの取引所で、価格を固定できるような trading bot、またはアルゴリズムはあるものでしょうか？

いま、[ccxt](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt)というライブラリのpythonプログラムを使用して、仮想通貨のtrading bot のようなものを勉強がてら作成しています。

ちょっと誰もやっていないような、価格固定のアルゴリズムがないかと、遊び心でやっております。

その際に、例えば Aコイン というものがあってある取引所で 100円 だとします。
こちらのコインをその取引所で、100円に固定するために

1. 価格が高かったら100円で売って
2. 低かったら100円で買う

というロジックを考えていて板の厚さにもよると思うんですが、どのような数量のorderを入れればよいのか考えあぐねており汗

参考になるようなサイトや、アルゴリズムがあれば識者の方にお伺いしたく m(_ _)m

Comment: 価格が高かったら100円で買って -> 価格が高かったら100円で売って
低かったら100円で売る -> 低かったら100円で買う

の間違いでした

Answer (score 0):

100円に固定するためには、99円以下で売る者と、101円以上で買う者を排除する必要があります。

「価格が高かったら100円で買って」というのは無理です。101円以上の価値のあるものを100円で売る者は居ませんから。
「低かったら100円で売る」というのも無理です。99円以下(低い)で買えるものを100円で買う者は居ませんから。

まぁ、遊びに世知辛い現実をつきつけるのは野暮でしょうが。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！

1. 価格が高かったら100円で売って
2. 低かったら100円で買う

の間違いでした、、、

これを無限？に続けていけば、100円にならないまでも近い値で推移するのではないかなと。ただ、その際に数量はどんなロジックがよいのかわからなかったんです。

Comment: 1から初めて足りなかったら、倍々にしていくのはどうでしょう？

Comment: たしかに、それは試してみる価値ありそうです！早速ロジックに入れてみようと思います^ ^